# How secure is an Apache2 virtual server which is listening on a private IP, to provide access only to the VPN

Tags: apache-2.2, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu 12.05 on a VPS where I run Apache 2.2 and OpenVPN - both on the same public ip. My intention was to set up an area in my Apache webserver which I will be able to access only while I am connected to the VPN (using the OpenVPN), for various tools that I prefer to not be publicly accessible at all - so a password-based setup won't work in this scenario.

Ok, `ifconfig` shows me that the `tun0` interface has the class A ip `10.8.0.1`. I went to update the DNS zone of my `example.com` domain and I have added an `A` record on the, let's say, `private.example.com` subdomain - which will resolve to `10.8.0.1`.
On the other hand, on the Apache configuration, I have added a virtual host which will listen to `10.8.0.1` (`<VirtualHost 10.8.0.1:80> [...]`).

This works great - now I can access `private.example.com` only when I am connected to that VPN, but **how secure is this setup?** Are there any obvious drawbacks which I don't see; is this setup something that is usually used?
*Note: of course, let's consider that neither the Apache2 nor the VPN has been compromised by other means.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the VPN isn't compromised what you're talking about isn't wholly unreasonable.

I'd consider adding an `iptables` rule for a belt-and-suspenders approach, like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 10.8.0.1 -i ! tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

That should drop any incoming segments destined TCP port 80 on 10.8.0.1 unless the source interface is `tun0`. (I'm assuming you're either running a default-permissive INPUT chain or you'll have an explicit rule to allow this traffic, too.)

I'd probably further that belt-and-suspenders stragtey by requiring authentication on the VPN-facing website, too, but that's just my excessive paranoia.

Comment: Thank you, it's a great help - I wouldn't have realized that the packages might still go there, with my current knowledge.